# Options.ConfigurationExtensions uses a higher version than the referenced version of Configuration.Abstractions

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

This is not a build error but a warning:

> Assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions' with identity 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions' with identity 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' [netcoreapp1.0]

Given that my project.json looks like this, I am not sure how to resolve the version mismatch.

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        "debugType": "portable",
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp10": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                    "type": "platform",
                    "version": "1.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding the following dependency. The same warning persists though.

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0"
```

How do we resolve the version mismatch warning that causes these red squigglies in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: Does clearing the nuget cache helps? `C:\Users\<User>\.nuget` on Windows, dunno on other OS'

Comment: @Tseng No. That does not help. Thank you for the tip.